# Sql Query to fetch fare price from csv database

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

i have database in csv format, and i want to calculate fare from one station to another station but problem is database, i think is not in proper format to build SQL query, so can we try sql query from below database format to fetch fare price from versova to sakinaka as an example.

[image: Database screenshot]

also is there any other solution table structure which will be friendly for firing sql queries on it.

Comment: (source, destination, fare) seems to be a logical choice

Comment: @smart developer. Yes, this is a **spreadsheet**, not a **database table** (let alone a **database**). See normalization.

Comment: in (source, destination, fare) structure i will have to provide all probably possible combination yes? that i think is not good way ,and also is there any other structure possible? @Fabricator

Comment: @Strawberry yes it is spreadsheet, can you make this spreadsheet in database friendly structure other than (source, destination, fare)  structure

Comment: @Fabricator's suggestion is a good one.

Comment: If you don't like @Fabricator's suggestion, can you explain why not?

Comment: @NevilleK  if i used fabricator's suggestion i would have provide all possible combination of source and destination i.e  144 combination of source and destination e.g versova-d n nagar 10, versova-azad nagar 20 etc combinations of all stations which is very long process i think and there should be another feasible way i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load your CSV into a System.Data.DataTable (C#).

```
Create Table T_Hop
   HOP_Id integer not NULL
   ,HOP_Name nvarchar(200) 


Create Table T_Fare 
     Fare_Id integer not null 
    ,Fare_Departure_HOP_Id integer not null 
    ,Fare_Destination_HOP_Id integer not null 
    ,Fare_Fare numeric(10, 2) not null
```

take first row 
foreach column ==> add hop name with id = ordinal index of column

```
for(int i=0; i < dt.Columns.Count; ++i)
{
for(int j=0; j < dt.Rows.Count; ++j)
{
    double Fare = System.Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[j][i]);
    ==> insert into T_Fare(Fare_Id,Fare_Departure_HOP_Id, Fare_Destination_HOP_Id, Fare_Fare ) Values (j*dt.Columns.Count + i, i, j, Fare)
    // and check that I didn't mix up i and j
}
}
```

Query:

```
SELECT Fare_Fare 
WHERE Fare_Destionation_HopId = x 
and Fare_Departure_Hop_Id = y
```